# In Report Builder 3.0 to group the two columns in one cell?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report and there is a column:

```
 Date begin     Date End
-----------    ----------
[date_begin]   [date_end]
```

Now I need to combine them into a single cell and rename as the date:
The result should be:

```
           Date
------------   ---------
    begin         end
------------   ---------
[date_begin]   [date_end]
```

How to do it,
 I tried through 'Add group'-->'Parent group'? `Report Builder 3.0`

Comment: No need to add parent group, just select both these columns by pressing ctrl and mouse selections > right click >  merge columns.

Comment: @ Shilpa Soni, I combined, and now how to add  begin,end

Comment: @Shilpa Soni, yes, now how to add begin,end

Comment: @Shilpa Soni, How add each column heading begin, end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't even bother to merge these cells.

Simply create an additional row above the  "Date Begin" and "Date End". This can be done by right clicking on the top row and select insert row.

Then merge the two cells above the "Date Begin" and "Date End" cells and type your description "Date" in the merged cell.

This should get you to the output that you seem to require. Unless there is another reason why you require these in the same cell?

Answer (score 0):

To show data from 2 or more fields of the dataset in a single cell you can either select cells and then click `Merge` in the context menu, or modify the expression in the target cell to be something like:

```
=Fields!date_begin.Value & " to " & Fields!date_end.Value
```